# Is it possible to have a gridview with different column width in android?

Tags: android

I need 3 columns like below:

==1==|=============2==============|======3====|
=====|============================|===========|

Comment: Yes... why don't you use Google? (sigh) Search for `android gridlayout`

Comment: @Hrundi V. Bakshi I used google, but I didn't find any solution by using gridView not gridLayout. I already have implemented the application using gridView and I don't want to change it because take me a lot of time.

Comment: The Grid**View** doesn't allow the tiles to be different. That's why I suggested you to use the Grid**Layout**, instead. By the way, the straight answer to your question is **NO**.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you may be better of using a TableLayout